# Compass sprite avanced

Tags: html, css, sass, sprite

I have a small question about the creation in "advanced" sprite with Compass mode. When I say "advanced mode" is storing the sprite in a variable, I prefer this method :)

Anyway, my problem is that I can not customized the image to half. Let me explain:

Managed space, the position of icons and layout, no problem. However, it is targeting a single icon that I have a problem. In according to the doc Compass, simply do this :

```
$sprite: sprite-map("sprite/*.png",
        $layout: vertical,
        $spacing: 50px,
        $position: 50%,
        $facebook-position: 100%); // position icon facebook, don't work
```

But it does not work, either with $facebook-position or $facebook-spacing, that icon does not move :(

Is a user Compass advanced drag on around here? :D

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At some point I faced a similar problem and if I remember right it worked for me if I used the map (folder) name as prefix (in your example `$sprite-facebook-position` instead of just `$facebook-position`).

This is obviously not how it should be according to the [example](https://gist.github.com/chriseppstein/747970) in current [Compass documentation](http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/spriting/) (also [here](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/helpers/sprites/#sprite-map)) - but maybe it was in some older version of Compass, I don't remember - so hopefully it fixes your problem.

Also note that your settings might not affect the first (respective) sprite on the sprites-map. So if you adjust the `spacing` of the first sprite it will only change the position of all following sprites. And that for example on a vertical sprite layout `position` set in percentages will not change anything if all sprites are of the same width. This two are examples where the settings might be working, but you just wouldn't see an effect.

Comment: Thank you so much! Indeed, it was nice to be able to save $sprite-facebook-spacing/position configured one sprite.

The documentation compass is yet indicate $name-icon-OPTION ..

Again thank you :)